# With new move semantics, when should you not use a reference in scope?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code where `foo` has a signature of `some_type_t foo();`

```
auto const result = foo();    // copy
auto const & result = foo();
auto const && result = foo();
```

In this case, using `auto const` would be a wasteful copy. The second and third case are the only way to access the data returned from `foo` without an extra copy. The second and third are identical.

Here is another snippet

```
auto result = foo();    // copy
auto & result = foo();  // error
auto && result = foo();
```

In this snippet, the second case would not compile as there is no way to bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference. The first case copies the result while the third case "grabs" the return from `foo` and directly without copy.

With this in mind, when would you ever not have a `&` when declaring a variable in scope? It seems that, as long as you always access result with `std::move(result)`, it is always more beneficial to have a reference.

Comment: `auto result = foo();` will not make a copy if the compiler uses [(N)RVO/copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to optimize away the temp object returned by `foo()` so that `result` gets directly initialized inside of `foo()`

Comment: "*In this case, using auto const would be a wasteful copy.*" No, it would not. Your question is tagged C++17, so there is no copying from the prvalue returned by `foo`. It may be that `foo` needed to do a copy into its return value, but that's what `foo` does, and how you access the returned prvalue won't change that.

Comment: "The second and third are identical." - they are not. The third is only valid if `foo()` is an rvalue, while the second is always valid... and when both are valid, they yield different types.

Answer (score 2):

None of these result in a copy or move, contrary to the premise of the question:

```
auto const result = foo();    // (1)
auto const & result = foo();  // (2)
auto const && result = foo(); // (3)
auto result = foo();          // (4)
auto & result = foo();        // (5) error
auto && result = foo();       // (6)
```

So what are the advantages/disadvantages?

(2), (3) and (6) use lifetime extension to ensure the result of `foo()` lives long enough to be used. This is fragile under very simple refactoring:

```
auto const & result = std::max(foo(), 1); // compiles, but broken
```

(3) and (6) rely on the temporary nature of the return value, so in a way, they break encapsulation of `foo`. I will explain what I mean by that. Imagine that `foo` is expensive and you wish to cache the value somewhere. Then you would change `foo()` to return a `const some_type_t&`. The choice between these options *could* be viewed as an implementation detail of `foo`. How would it change the initializations: (1) and (4) would still be valid but introduce a copy, (2) works the same, and (3) and (6) no longer compile.

So one has to decide between silently broken under some change (2) (3) and (6), loudly broken under some change (3) and (6), and never broken but possibly slower under change (1) and (4). This depends on the priorities of the system being built. One can imagine systems where it is more important not to break existing correct code than to avoid a silent extra copy under refactoring. In such a system, (1) and (4) might be preferred.

Alternatively, one could approach it from a perspective of what the code at this initialization site tells us. This point of view will be more relevant if code review is part of your development process. (2), (3) and (6) tell us nothing about the lifetime of result referred to because `foo()` may return a reference. So we need more context. But (1) and (4) are explicit about lifetime, so they give us more information.

It's C++. We have many options for initialization and resource lifetime, and they all have trade-offs.